# Huge operation in PHP

Tags: php

I am converting a Java program into PHP for a webpage, the only problem is that I am using a free web hosting service (000Webhost) and it does not let me make time limit changes. The program compiles data from (currently, 66, however, more are possible) different webpages, and puts the data into a table. I can provide code, though, I am by no means a PHP scripter, so that may be the source of my problems. Can someone help me figure out my issues?

```
    <?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.someURL.com");
$newString = explode("data = [", $html);
$sOne = explode("]", $newString[1]);
$names = explode(", ", $sOne[0]);

$urls = array();

foreach($names as $name) {
$chars = str_split($name);

foreach ($chars as $ch) {
if (!ctype_alnum($ch) && $ch != '-' && $ch != '_' && $ch != ' ') {
            $name = trim(str_replace($ch, ' ', $name));
        }
    }

    $urls[count($urls)] = 'http://www.someURL.com/' .str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
}

echo count($urls);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++) {
$url = $urls[$i];
$html = @file($url);

if (strpos($html, "404 - Page not found") === false) {
echo $i;
flush(); @ob_flush();
}
}

echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
?>
```

The echos in there are a debug, telling me how many pages I need to process, and how many I actually have processed.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh god please don't suppress errors with the error control operator (`@`). It just makes everything harder.

Comment: Alright... Ill take those out.

Comment: What are your issues? Just script timeout? Is there any reason you actually need to run all these requests serially in a loop?  Have you tried parallelizing the calls or running a fewer number of requests per script execution, with some means to queue up the URL's for processing?

Comment: **use cURL** for fetching URL's **$html = @file($url);** is really bad.

Comment: My issues are just script timeout, I do not know what you mean by 'serially', but I need to process all of the url's to make a table in the html page that the php is in.

Comment: @AdrianPreuß, I am not familiar with cURL, is that using fopen and what not?

Comment: Show initiative. http://php.net/curl

Answer (score 0):

you can run you php processing in a local host, WAMP, LAMP , XAMP etc, and then change your php time limit to 0 (unlimited) , fill the local DB in all the data you just saved and then move the local db to the production db